# How to get the real length of string?

Tags: javascript

**Code :**

```
str = String.fromCharCode(2000000000000000000000000)
```

Alright, `str` actually = `""`. But `str.length = 1.`

What should I do to get the real length?

Any help could be  highly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Define "real length". If you want to avoid counting characters with code 0 you can `[].filter.call(str, function(item){return item.charCodeAt(0)}).length`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, @YuryTarabanko. You can write an answer to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your statement cannot convert that character code into a character, so it returns the null character, your `str` variable is a single character with the `charcode 0`.

```
str = String.fromCharCode(2000000000000000000000000)
   ""
str.length
   1
str.charCodeAt(0) // First char
   0
str.charCodeAt(1) // Non-existant char for reference
   NaN
```

Comment: So how can I make it return 0 in this case?

Comment: @user3698272 You can't, because its length is not 0 but 1. You could do `if( str === String.fromCharCode(0) ) { str = ""; }` to clear the null character.